# AD users in Snow Leopard with admin privileges

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, apple

I've just authenticated my first Apple machine onto the active directory infrastructure. Yay!

The only thing I'm having problems with is specifying that the AD user is an administrator, and able to make changes. I don't see any interface for that.

Is there an interface in the system by default, or do I have to download the Server Admin Tools?

Comment: Matt, do you mean making the user a local admin of the Mac, or a domain admin?

Comment: Local admin on the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There way to add directory users to the local administrators (or any other local group) of a machine:

1. Connect to localhost with Workgroup Manager
2. From the directory drop-down on the top-left, select "Local"
3. Select the group you want to operate on
4. Click the members tab of the group
5. Click the plus button to add a member
6. At the top of the slide-out list select your directory instead of the local directory
7. Drag the desired member or group in to the local group

Comment: Oh man, I'm so close. I want to make my domain user an administrator, but none of the built-in groups are showing up. Any tips?

Comment: Got it. Need to go to "View", then "System Users" or something very close to that

Answer (score 1):

For the machine, Directory Services has moved from Utilities (Leopard) to System -> Core Services.

In here you can add specific users/AD groups to admin the machine.

Answer (score 0):

In Leopard, at least, you can only specify *groups* with local administrative privileges.  You can specify "ManagedBy" attributes in AD if you want to enable admin access for particular users.